# Как загрузить контент в блок на странице Framework7

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5, framework, mobile-development

Пытаюсь разобраться с Framework 7.

Сделал всё как в примере: http://framework7.io/get-started/

Хочу, в div с классом: page-content загрузить контент с другой страницы по AJAX-запросу и никак не пойму как это сделать?

Фрагмент кода:

```
<div data-page="index" class="page">
    <div class="page-content"></div>
</div>
```

Что я пытался сделать:

> var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main')
>   mainView.router.loadPage('about.html');

Вижу что AJAX-запрос идет, но контент не загружается!

Нашёл такое решение:

> $$.get(url, null, function (data) {   $$('.page-content').html(data);
>   });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$.get(mainUrl + '/conference/conference/mList', null, function (data)
>   {   $$('.page-content').html(data); });